# Visual Basic OCR - Build Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use OCR with VB , i found this awesome code on the internet but when i complete the project and run it it gives me these errors:

Error   1   'Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Error   2   'Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Code :

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.OCR
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Public Class Form1

    Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT)
    Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X + 4, Me.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y + 30), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)
    PictureBox1.Image = pic
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing

    End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic))
    RichTextBox1.Text = OCRz.GetText

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Rename the subs shown in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Windows Forms? or Web forms? In any case the designer has probably inserted handlers for these events in the code behind.  Try using the show all files to view the designer code.  Or better yet open the designer go to the event property sheet (click on the control in question) and remove (or rename) the designer's handlers.   Or rename your own if you want the designer's handlers to run too.